# "Please consider adding a comment" yet the question is locked and therefore unable to be commented on

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, locked-questions, comment-lock

Basically this is a contradiction:

> [image: "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." popup notice after downvoting a question that is locked; it has the message "Locked for 24 days. Comments on this question have been disabled, but it is still accepting new answers and other interactions. Learn more." Free-hand circles in a medium-to-dark shade of orange draw a contrast between the two mismatched parts of the texts, highlighting its peculiarity.]

The popup notice

> **Please consider adding a comment** if you think this post can be improved.

appears after downvoting a locked question

> Locked for 24 days. **Comments on this question have been disabled**, but it is still accepting new answers and other interactions. Learn more.

It was on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction).

I feel this is undesirable behavior, and so I submit this as a bug report.  I suggest blocking the comment-suggesting popup in cases when comments are prevented.

Comment: I added the `comment-lock` tag because I think it's only applicable for it. I think a "full lock" doesn't allow voting so you cannot get the message to add a comment. I may be missing some type of lock here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. I went in and disallowed this popup from appearing if the user is unable to comment on the post.